# How do I factor $x^3+6x+20$?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have polynomial $f(x) = x^3+6x+20$ and we factorize it to $(x+2)(x^2-2x+10)$. How can we further factor it to $(x+2)(x-1+3i)(x-1-3i)$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: We "factor," not "factorize" a polynomial.

Comment: @MarkViola: Is this a AmE/BrE distinction? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/factor says FACTOR (verb) = another term for FACTORIZE.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $$x^2-2x +10 = x^2-2x+1 + 9 = (x-1)^2 - (3i)^2.$$ $$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y).$$